# Show uialertview after opening an app after 3 times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Is it possible to show a Alertview when opening an app after lets say 3 times? Can this be done with NSUserDefaults?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, storing the launch count in `NSUserDefaults` would be a typical solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
int launches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
if (launches > 3) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert" 
                                                  message:@"Some message" delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:launches+1 forKey:@"launchCount"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I add this code into viewDidAppear in my viewcontroller nothing happens after re-opening after 3 times.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the last line, what is the value of `launches` for each launch?

Comment: Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead. When I add your code into ViewDidLoad it always shows the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"launchCount"]==0){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:1 forKey:@"launchCount"];

    }else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"launchCount"]+1 forKey:@"launchCount"];

    }
```

Comment: This answer needs a lot of work. Where does it go? How does this show the alert view? Why have this `if` statement at all? Just get the value, increment it, store it. You don't need a special check for `0`. And Use a variable. No need to read the current value twice as you do.

Comment: @NofelMahmood thnx! Do you have a example code how to do this? Thanks a million!

Comment: @rmaddy thnx! Do you have a example code how to do this? Thanks a million!