# Show UIAlertview after 3 launches App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uialertview

What I'm trying to achieve is to show a UIAlertview when a user opens the app after 3 times. I use the code below in my ViewDidAppear's ViewController, but it shows the UIAlertview everytime when opening the app. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
int launches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
if (launches > 3) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert" 
                                                  message:@"Some message" delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:launches+1 forKey:@"launchCount"];
```

Edit: I'm also getting a NSInteger (aka 'long') to 'int' warning. Could this be the issue why it's not working?

[image]

Comment: To fix the warning, change `int` to `NSInteger`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show uialertview after opening an app after 3 times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471780/show-uialertview-after-opening-an-app-after-3-times) What purpose was there asking the same question twice?

Answer (score 0):

You should move that code to your app delegate in 
`-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Nope, that will still show the warning and the alert view popups everytime when opening the app.

Comment: Check what value is returned for launches on the first launch. Also, do you want the alert to appear EVERY time the app launches after the 3rd launch, or just the 3rd launch?

Comment: How can I check what value is returned? Yes, I wanna show it every time when the app launches after the 3th launch.

Comment: There are three good ways to debug the values: 1. Set a breakpoint after `launches` has been returned (line 44). 2. Print the value to the console using `NSLog`. 3. Do step 1 and type "po launches" into the console.

Comment: See screenshot, it shows a strange value on launches [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10965320/launches.png)

Comment: Step over that line to line 49. In your picture the code on line 48 has not run yet so `launches` hasn't been set yet.

Comment: AH, put the breakpoint on the last line, it shows launches 51 at NSInteger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63367/discussion-between-jan-and-adampro13).

Answer (score 0):

@AdamPro13 is right that you should move the code but probably to `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` in your app delegate. The `viewDidAppear` method can be called several times for each app launch. If you want to show the `UIAlertView` only once per installation you could either save a `BOOL` if it has been shown or change the test `launches == 4`. Something like

```
NSInteger launches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
BOOL launchAlertShown = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"launchAlertShown"];
if (launches > 3 && !launchAlertShown) {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert" 
                                              message:@"Some message" delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"launchAlertShown"];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:launches+1 forKey:@"launchCount"];
```

You have delete the app, not just overwrite with a new build, to delete the contents of `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. This means that the test `launches > 3` will remain true until you have deleted the app from the device or simulator that you are testing on.,

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks to @AdamPro13

```
NSInteger launches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    if (launches % 3 == 0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                        message:@"Some message" delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:launches+1 forKey:@"launchCount"];
```